# Can I unlock Crushing mode in Uncharted 2 after using a costume?

Tags: ps3, uncharted-2

I am playing a New Game on Hard, but I switched my costume once during my play-through.  Will this mess up my ability to unlock Crushing when I beat the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game disables certain "game altering" cheats (like one-shot kills, unlimited ammo) on difficulties you haven't finished the game on already, if it allows you to change costume, it shouldn't lock trophies or your ability to unlock Crushing